# I intercept calls to microcontroller registers

Tags: c, embedded, cpu-registers, intercept

Unit testing embedded C for a TI MSP430. Unit tests are to run on a Linux host compiled with GCC. The project is rather big and primarily legacy code.

There are reads and writes to registers such as PCIN_L, PCOUT_L, and PCDIR_L among others that when compiled will generate errors saying they are undeclared. This is true because when running on the host no such registers exist.
Earlier I learned to intercept calls to functions (symbols) that would not be available and redirect thos calls to fake functions, only returning a predefined value. This I did using the linker option `-Wl --wrap,someSymbol`.

```
Makefile:
LDFLAGS=-Wl --wrap,AbsentFunction
SOURCES=WrappedFunctions.c

WrappedFunctions.c:
int __wrap_AbsentFunction(int val_a)
{
   return val_a;
}
```

This would redirect any calls to `AbsentFunction` to `__wrap_AbsentFunction`.
I did however try this on my registers as well withou any luck.

```
Makefile:
LDFLAGS=-Wl --wrap,PCDIR_L
SOURCES=WrappedSymbols.c

WrappedSymbols.c:
char __wrap_PCDIR_L;
```

Is it possible to something similar to the registers as I did to the functions? I prefer not introducing changes into the projects code.

Comment: At a minimum, please show exactly how the registers are accessed in the real code.

Comment: Just write teeny helper functions that read/write the registers.  You can wrap those.

Comment: @unwind,<br>
In MSP430c54c.h: `#define P6DIR (PCDIR_H)`
In external_link.h: `#define PA_PINS_AS_OUTPUT (P6DIR |= 0x30)
In external_link.c: `PA_PIN_AS_OUTPUT;`

Comment: @HansPassant That is a very good alternative. I would prefer not altering the original code, but if I must, I must! Sorry about the formatting in the above comment, i tried to get som line breaks in there but then the 5 min limit was passed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply declare memory mapped processor peripheral registers as volatile data by creating a "fake" processor header containing declarations such as:

```
extern volatile uint16_t PCDIR_L ;
```

They will not of course behave like peripheral registers but it will allow the code to be built.

A better approach is to have built a hardware abstraction layer so that peripheral access is via an function API rather than direct to the hardware, then you can create a "fake" API that emulates the hardware behaviour.

Comment: Can I in the compiler say which of the MSP430x54x.h header files that should be used, mine (containing the declaration above) or the original? Or am I forced to introducing `#if defined UNITTEST` in the original code, switching between includes? ... Your abstraction API is the same sollution as Hans's above right?

Comment: @Enok82 : The simplest solution is to have two separate MSP430x54x.h files in different directories, and provide a different include file search path to the unit test build.

Comment: It's working. I had to remove the `extern` though. Having two MSP430x54x.h header files i used the `-isystem dir` gcc option to switch to my own one like so: `gcc -isystem /myincludes/ -c foo.c`. Other options available are also `-I` that is equal to `-isystem` and `-iquote` for those local header files you include with  "" instead of <>. ... Thank you very much!

Comment: @Enok82 : Without the `extern`, you are *instantiating* an object rather than simply *declaring* one.  That will cause problems if the header is included in more than one compilation unit and they are linked.  I had assumed that you knew that given a declaration, you would also need a *single* definition in a .c file somewhere else.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the externs' use. In this case there is no other natural place to put the _instantiations_ of the objects. Besides instantiating them elsewhere would create duplicates that would be a hassle to update. I am considering wrapping the declarations/instantiations in something similar to: `#ifndef INSTANTIATE_GLOBALS \n #define EXT extern \n #else \n #define EXT \n #endif` and then declaring the variables using `EXT` instead of `extern`. `INSTANTIATE_GLOBALS` would be defined and undefined around the entrypoint modules' inclusion of the header file.

Comment: @Enok82 :  I don't see your point - you have a fake_MSP430x54x.c file and instantiate the "register" data there - the unit test project links that file, the target project does not.  Simple.

Comment: Ahh... simple! Since the original project doesn't have any MSP430x54x.c I never considered creating one for the unit test project only. The only downside I see is the need to update in two places, but that's no biggie. I might add that I'm not the most experienced developer... yet!

Answer (score 0):

The register names for the MSP430 device are all declared in a device specific header file.  While you will not necessarily be able to mimic easily the behaviour of these registers, you can write your own equivalent file that will map the registers on to memory locations accessible to your program.

Mimicking the bitwise functionality of port registers, serial port status registers and the rest will be quite an undertaking.

Comment: that solution would look something similar to the one Clifford suggested?